# How to get type declared from Iterable in Scala?

Tags: json, scala, type-erasure

I am wondering if there is way to get the declared type in the underlying Iterable as in:

```
var string: Seq[String] => I want something to return String 
var int: Seq[Int] = _ => I want something to return Int
var genericType: Seq[A] => I want to return A
```

I need to know the class of these types so I can use the underlying Json Library to deserialize the json string into this type.

Something like

```
def fromJson[A](jsonString: String)(implicit tag: TypeTag[A]): A =  ???
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might have not provided enough information in my question. Anyway, I found out the answer.

In order to retrieve a class from a generic type I had to do the following

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
val m = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
def myMethod[A](implicit t: TypeTag[A]) = {
  val aType = typeOf[A]
  aType.typeArgs match {
     case x: List[_] if x.nonEmpty => m.runtimeClass(x.head)
     case x: List[_] if x.isEmpty => m.runtimeClass(aType)
  }
}
scala> myMethod[Seq[String]]
res3: Class[_] = class java.lang.String

scala> myMethod[Seq[Int]]
res4: Class[_] = int

scala> case class Person(name: String)
defined class Person

scala> myMethod[Seq[Person]]
res5: Class[_] = class Person

scala> myMethod[Person]
res6: Class[_] = class Person
```

I can then provide this class to the underlying library to do its job. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> class A(i: Int) {
 | override def toString = "A("+i+")"
 | }
defined class A

scala> class B(i: Int) extends A(i) {
 | override def toString = "B("+i+")"
 | }
defined class B

scala> val list: List[A] = List(new A(1), new B(2), new B(3), new A(4))
list: List[A] = List(A(1), B(2), B(3), A(4)) 

// if you just want the name of class

// full class name with package info
scala> val fullClassNameList = list.map(s => s.getClass.getName)
fullClassNameList: List[String] = List(A, B, B, A)


// If you want the actual runtime Type

scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe=>ru}
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe=>ru}

scala> def getTypeTag[T: ru.TypeTag](obj: T) = ru.typeTag[T]
getTypeTag: [T](obj: T)(implicit evidence$1: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[T])reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[T]

// if you just wanted to find the Type parameter of the List,

// get TypeTag of list
val listTypeTag = getTypeTag(list)
listTypeTag: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[List[A]] = TypeTag[scala.List[A]]

// get Type of list
scala> val listType = listTypeTag.tpe
listType: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = scala.List[A]

// get TypeArgs of the Type of list
scala> val listTypeArgs = listType.typeArgs
listTypeArgs: List[reflect.runtime.universe.Type] = List(A)

// Now, we know that List[A] takes just 1 type parameter
// that is the type we are looking for
scala> val theTypeOfList = listTypeArgs.head
theTypeOfList: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = A
```

Comment: Thank you Sarvesh for the above. I think what I need to be able to get access to is A.getClass, for example List[Person] then I'd need to know it's a Person so I can call Person.getClass. This is to provide to the underlying library such as Jackson ObjectMapper that uses reflection. Might be another way to define my method to take in the Class as well e.g def fromJson(jsonString: String, class: Class) I was trying to avoid that.